# NancyFx: how to pass an error message to a custom error page?

Tags: c#, razor, nancy

We've implemented static custom error pages for 404/500 HTTP status codes using Razor and the IStatusCodeHandler implementation documented here:

https://blog.tommyparnell.com/custom-error-pages-in-nancy/

That works, and now we've been trying to pass an error message to the Razor template.  The RenderView method runs without exception, however the output is totally blank.

In the Handle method, we construct an ErrorModel object and set its ErrorMessage property, then pass the object to RenderView:

```
var response = viewRenderer.RenderView(context, "views/Errors/" + (int)statusCode + ".cshtml", errorModel);
```

The CustomStatusCode.cs code is:

```
public class CustomStatusCode : IStatusCodeHandler
{
    private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger<CustomStatusCode>();

    private static IEnumerable<int> _checks = new List<int>();
    public static IEnumerable<int> Checks { get { return _checks; } }
    private IViewRenderer viewRenderer;
    public CustomStatusCode(IViewRenderer viewRenderer)
    {
        this.viewRenderer = viewRenderer;
    }

    public bool HandlesStatusCode(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        return (_checks.Any(x => x == (int)statusCode));
    }

    public static void AddCode(int code)
    {
        AddCode(new List<int>() { code });
    }

    public static void AddCode(IEnumerable<int> code)
    {
        _checks = _checks.Union(code);
    }

    public static void RemoveCode(int code)
    {
        RemoveCode(new List<int>() { code });
    }

    public static void RemoveCode(IEnumerable<int> code)
    {
        _checks = _checks.Except(code);
    }

    public static void Disable()
    {
        _checks = new List<int>();
    }

    public void Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        var errorMessage = string.Empty;
        var exception = context.GetException();
        if (exception != null)
        {
            errorMessage = exception.Message;
        }
        var errorModel = new ErrorModel(errorMessage);

        try
        {
            var response = viewRenderer.RenderView(context, "views/Errors/" + (int)statusCode + ".cshtml", errorModel);

            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            context.Response = response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Debug($"CustomStatusCodes caught exception: {ex.Message}");

            RemoveCode((int)statusCode);
            context.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        }
    }

}
```

The ErrorModel.cs class is:

```
public class ErrorModel
{
    public ErrorModel(string message)
    {
        ErrorMessage = message;
    }

    string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

One of the Razor templates:

```
@using WebService.Models
@Model ErrorModel

<html>
<body>
    <b>500 Internal server error.</b>
    <p>Error message was: @Model.ErrorMessage</p>
</body>
</html>
```

We've tried setting response.StatusCode to the original statusCode parameter value, as well as HttpStatusCode.OK, both result in a blank page.

Any suggestions as to what we're missing?

Comment: Not sure what your AddCode/RemoveCode is. Remove them. In your HandlesStatusCode method return statusCode == 500; Then in a module throw an Exception and see what response you get. The rest of the StatusCodeHandler seems correct